# Need to match end of every term in a vector with a certain term R

Tags: r

I have an original vector, samples, and want to subset it so that I have a smaller vector, tum, containing only terms that end in "01A". I have tried using grepl, grep, and subsetting, but it gives me incorrect values.

Here is what the code looks like:

```
samples <- lihc_data[0,-1]
as.vector(samples)
tum <- subset(lihc_data[0,-1], grepl("01A$", lihc_data[0,-1]) == TRUE)
```

here is a bit of what the samples vector looks like:

```
 [1] TCGA.BC.A10Q.11A TCGA.BC.A10Q.01A TCGA.DD.A1EB.11A TCGA.DD.A1EB.01A
 [5] TCGA.DD.A1EG.11A TCGA.DD.A1EG.01A TCGA.DD.A1EH.11A TCGA.DD.A1EH.01A
 [9] TCGA.DD.A1EI.11A TCGA.DD.A1EI.01A TCGA.DD.A3A6.11A TCGA.DD.A3A6.01A
```

Answer (score 1):

The 0 is strange in `lihc_data[0,-1]`. In R you never have 0 indices afaik, in contrast with other programming languages. So your vector is probably empty. Maybe try `as.character(lihc_data[1,-1])` if you want the first line of the lihc_data data.frame or matrix without the first element.

Based on your code this seems to work :

```
samples <- c("TCGA.BC.A10Q.11A", "TCGA.BC.A10Q.01A", "TCGA.DD.A1EB.11A", 
             "TCGA.DD.A1EB.01A", "TCGA.DD.A1EG.11A", "TCGA.DD.A1EG.01A", 
             "TCGA.DD.A1EH.11A", "TCGA.DD.A1EH.01A", "TCGA.DD.A1EI.11A", 
             "TCGA.DD.A1EI.01A", "TCGA.DD.A3A6.11A", "TCGA.DD.A3A6.01A")

subset(samples, grepl("01A$", samples) == TRUE)
```

And this is probably shorter and more idiomatic (same result) :

```
grep("01A$", samples, value = TRUE)
samples[grepl("01A$", samples)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
samples <- c("TCGA.BC.A10Q.11A", "TCGA.BC.A10Q.01A", "TCGA.DD.A1EB.11A",
             "TCGA.DD.A1EB.01A", "TCGA.DD.A1EG.11A", "TCGA.DD.A1EG.01A", 
             "TCGA.DD.A1EH.11A", "TCGA.DD.A1EH.01A", "TCGA.DD.A1EI.11A",
             "TCGA.DD.A1EI.01A", "TCGA.DD.A3A6.11A", "TCGA.DD.A3A6.01A")

stringr::str_extract_all(samples, "[:print:]{12}\\.01A") %>% unlist()
```

Result:

```
[1] "TCGA.BC.A10Q.01A" "TCGA.DD.A1EB.01A" "TCGA.DD.A1EG.01A" "TCGA.DD.A1EH.01A"
[5] "TCGA.DD.A1EI.01A" "TCGA.DD.A3A6.01A"
```

Comment: This is clearly not what OP's input data is like. From how OP's `samples` vector is printed, it is clear that the first row is 4 separate values (see the bracketed cumulative count on the left hand side of the output) and not a string with 4 values separated by spaces...

Comment: If you are familiar with how R prints vectors, it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

A base solution:

the data:

```
 c("TCGA.DD.A1EG.11A", "TCGA.DD.A1EI.11A", "TCGA.DD.A1EG.01A", 
"TCGA.DD.A1EI.01A", "TCGA.DD.A1EH.11A", "TCGA.DD.A3A6.11A", "TCGA.DD.A1EH.01A", 
"TCGA.DD.A3A6.01A") -> samples
```

Then use simple vector subsetting (no need for the `subset` function):

```
samples[grepl("01A$", samples)]
```